# javascript (angularJS): add current time to date and format

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my app user select date, but i need to send to the server current time too.

Here is my init code:

```
  $scope.event = {
    'Name': '',
    'Date': $filter('date')(new Date(), 'yyyy-MM-dd'),
  };
```

but i need to change it to such format:

```
2015-01-20T20:00:00Z
```

is it real? how could i append current time to my input's value in format as i posted here?

i do it like this:

```
      var x = new Date(); 
      var h = x.getHours(); 
      var m = x.getMinutes(); 
      var s = x.getSeconds(); 
      var z = x.getTimezoneOffset();
      $scope.event.Date = $scope.event.Date + 'T' + h + ':' + m + ':' + s + z;
```

but seems that this code is to ugly, maybe i do something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like format you are after is [ISO 8601](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString) format:

```
$scope.event.Date = new Date().toISOString(); // "2015-03-04T14:28:19.616Z"
```

Comment: hm, but if i select future date or something so? what i need to pass to formatter (on input is string with date like 2061-11-20)?

Comment: Not sure I get you. You want `$scope.event.Date` to be future date and also formatted to ISO 8601?

Comment: like this: if date is today (like 04-03-2015) then use current time too, but if future or past, just add there 0:00 as time to date
also what i mean: for example your code get's current datetime, but how to get my input's date, and append there time?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look the examples in official API:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date

You can see something like this:

```
{{1288323623006 | date:'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z'}}: 2010-10-29 04:40:23 +0100
```

Then you can use 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ' as format instead of 'yyyy-MM-dd'

```
$scope.event = {
    'Name': '',
    'Date': $filter('date')(new Date(), 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ'),
  };
```